# Is there a way to delay a query in cronjob if the previous doesn't finsh yet?

Tags: mysql, cron

I have a cron job that fetches data from the MsSQL database and stores it in the MySQL database, sometimes it starts executing while the previous one has not finished yet.

I tried to coordinate the time between the copy duration and the time distance between the two queries, but I was not 100% successful.

Comment: This doesn't feel like a question for [so] but for [unix.se] (and I suspect there is a duplicate there).